# How can I change/mock services for my UnitTests?

Tags: unit-testing, dependency-injection, typo3, extbase

I'm using typo3 6 with extbase and some dependency injection features.

MyClass is injected with a service. The property which holds the service is **protected**.

```
class MyClass {
    /**
     *
     * @var \X\Y\Z\MyService
     * @inject
     */
    protected $myService;
}
```

How can I change (or mock) the service in my UnitTest by?

Comment: In my opinion you could use the method *injectMyService* from your fixture-class. The *@inject* only calls the magic-method *injectMyService*.

Answer (score 0):

I use reflection api to inject mock object to a protected field. See http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionobject.php